# awk replace column from another file but for a range of lines only

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to replace first column of a.com with first column for file b.com, but replacement should happens only for line number `6` to `5286`

I know

```
awk 'NR==6, NR==5286' a.com
```

-will select those lines

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
```

-will replace all the lines for those two file.
But how to combine these two commands so that replacement happens only for selected lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}FNR>5&&FNR<5287{$1=a[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
```